# Container isn't flowing with content

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi I'm using Wordpress,

Having a few problems with my container and an image caption.

Site: http://bit.ly/19QzWbS

The image caption seems to be overlapping no matter what I try and do.

I've tried this:

```
.entry-content .wp-caption {
/* border: 1px solid #E0E0E0; */
/* box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);*/
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
/* -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;*/
box-sizing: border-box;
/* margin: 5px 0 30px 0;*/
max-width: 100%;
padding: 8px;
text-align: center;
}
```

But I still think it's the container.

Thanks.

Comment: I see a photo with caption underneath, but there is no wrapping/overlapping. Which browser(s) are you seeing the issue in?

Comment: Hey Spacebean, it was in Chrome and Aurora(Firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi all problems is from style `float:left`

after `float: left` you must `clear:both`

in this div

```
<div class="symple-box blue none " style="text-align:left; width:100%;"> 


</div>
```

add this

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

in example like this

```
 <div class="symple-box blue none " style="text-align:left; width:100%;"> 
    your code

    <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
```

and this in css

```
.clear {
    clear: Both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```